# add route to yajra button

Tags: laravel, yajra-datatable

I need to make this record button as link to the route to display another blade file. also i need to pass variable with that route.

this is controller

```
$data = DB::table('vehicleregister')->orderBy('id')->get();

return datatables()->of($data)
->addIndexColumn()
->addColumn('action', function($data){

 

  $btn = '<div class="btn-group" role="group" >
  <button href="javascript:void(0)" type="button" data-id="'.$data->id.'" class="btn details btn-primary">Details</button>
  
  <button href="javascript:void(0)" type="button" data-id="'.$data->id.'" class="btn edit btn-secondary">Edit</button>
  <button href=""    type="button" data-id="'.$data->id.'" class="btn records btn-success">Records</button>
</div>';

return $btn;



})
->rawColumns(['action'])
->make(true);
```

i  also try to make it with javascript .

$('body').on('click','.records',function(){

var record_id = $(this).data('id');

});

Comment: Just replace `<button>` tag to `<a>` tag. and add link in the `href` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This, You need to use an anchor tag instead of a button tag.

```
$data = DB::table('vehicleregister')->orderBy('id')->get();

return datatables()->of($data)
    ->addIndexColumn()
    ->addColumn('action', function($data) {
 
    $btn = '<div class="btn-group" role="group" >
        <a href="' . route('route-name') . '" data-id="'.$data->id.'" class="btn details btn-primary">Details</a>
        <a href="' . route('route-name') . '" data-id="'.$data->id.'" class="btn edit btn-secondary">Edit</a>
        <a href="' . route('route-name') . '" data-id="'.$data->id.'" class="btn records btn-success">Records</a>
       </div>';

    return $btn;
})
->rawColumns(['action'])
->make(true);
```